# Having an Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Object android.util.Pair.first'

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have a plus and minus button for tickets buying, so when I'm clicking plus I'm adding to Map data how much tickets of type I'm buying, and vice versa when clicking minus button. But on some buttons there's such problem, when I click on button in 2-nd position and third there is such error:

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Object android.util.Pair.first' on a null object reference
        at ru.myapp.PaymentFragment.itemClicked(PaymentFragment.java:243)
        at ru.myapp.Adapters.PaymentAdapter$2.onClick(PaymentAdapter.java:101)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

And my code is like this is how I'm making plus-minus operations in my fragment:

```
   private Map<Integer, Pair<String, Integer>> tickets = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void itemClicked(View view, int position, String operation) {
    PaymentData paymentData = mArrayList.get(position);
    int counter;
    int ticket = Integer.parseInt(paymentData.getmPrice());
    if("plus".equals(operation)) {
        if(tickets.containsKey(ticket)) {
            Pair<String, Integer> value = tickets.get(ticket);
            tickets.put(ticket, Pair.create(value.first, value.second + 1));
            for ( int key : tickets.keySet() ) {
                counter = tickets.get(key).second;
                Log.e("TICKETS", key + " " + counter);
                counter *= key;
                priceForTV += counter;
            }
        } else {
            counter = 1;
            tickets.put(ticket, Pair.create(paymentData.getmTicketID(), counter));
            for ( int key : tickets.keySet() ) {
                counter = tickets.get(key).second;
                counter *= key;
                priceForTV += counter;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(tickets.containsKey(ticket)) {
            for ( int key : tickets.keySet() ) {
                Pair<String, Integer> value = tickets.get(ticket);
                tickets.put(ticket, Pair.create(value.first, value.second - 1));
                counter = tickets.get(key).second;
                if(counter > 0) {
                    counter *= key;
                    priceForTV += counter;
                } else if(counter == 0)  {
                    tickets.remove(key);
                } else {
                    tickets.remove(key);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( int key : tickets.keySet() ) {
                counter = tickets.get(key).second;
                counter *= key;
                priceForTV += counter;
            }
        }
    }
    mPriceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(priceForTV));
    priceForTV = 0;

    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Plus minus buttons are in the adapter:

```
holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.itemClicked(v, position, "plus");
            }

            int price = Integer.parseInt(holder.countTV.getText().toString());
            price += 1;
            if(price > 0) {
                holder.countTV.setText(String.valueOf(price));
                holder.countTV.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.redText));
            }

        }
    });
    holder.minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.itemClicked(v, position, "minus");
            }

            int price = Integer.parseInt(holder.countTV.getText().toString());
            if(price != 0) {
                price -= 1;
                holder.countTV.setText(String.valueOf(price));
                if(price == 0) {
                    holder.countTV.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.greyText));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Guess i have some noob mistake, and just can't find it, please help me :C